# How To Print Java Program / .Net Program Inside TextView?

Tags: android, database, printing, textview, store

Right now i'm doing an educational app.I stucked with some problem.

My app first page has list of java programs name like below

```
swap two numbers

find biggest number

reverse number
```

When user press a particular item- it has to go to detail screen and has to display particular program (i mean user press on swap of two no's need to navigate to detail page to display respective program)->right now its going detail view controller

For example I have program like this

/********print star pattern ************/

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class  Diamond 
 {


public static void main(String[] args)
{

Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter N : ");
int n=sc.nextInt();  
          System.out.print("Enter Symbol : ");

          char c = sc.next().charAt(0);

for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
           {
        for(int j=1;j<=n-i;j++)

                    {
                           System.out.print(" ");
                    }

                  for(int j=1;j<=i*2-1;j++)

                    {
                           System.out.print(c);
                    }
 System.out.println();

           }            
           for(int i=n-1;i>0;i--)
           {
        for(int j=1;j<=n-i;j++)

                    {
                           System.out.print(" ");
                    }
                  for(int j=1;j<=i*2-1;j++)

                    {
                           System.out.print(c);
                    }
    System.out.println();
           }  



}
```

}

How can I print above program in detail in view controller ?

Now am using textview, Is it okay to continue with it or Is any other component that i could make use of ?because some programs have more width and height.

or else any other mechanism is available to achieve this?

I researched a lot but didn't find solution.

Can someone suggest me how to go with this? where to store the program? How to display it?

Thanks.

Comment: Use webview instead of Textview.

Comment: if program width is more means it will scroll automatically(horizontally) is it??@Chirag Ravel

Comment: yes, Webview will handle it automatically but you need to pass html content to webview.

Comment: how to do that i mean do i need to store above program in html can you give me a idea or suggest me how to store that program or where can i store programs@ChiragRavel Thank you